# Difficult queryset for prefetch

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have models:

```
class Inote(IDeclaration):

    Time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    Author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)ss')

    __unicode__ = lambda s: str(s.id) + ' (%s)'%(s._meta.model_name)


class Article(Inote):

    Title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The models are linked by multitable inheritance. In my view I try get Articles through prefetch_related in queryset of User:

```
class UserList(ListView):
    model = User

    def get_queryset(self):

        qs = super(UserList, self).get_queryset().prefetch_related('inotes__article')

        for q in qs:
            for i in q.inotes.all():
                if hasattr(i,'article'):
                    print i.article

        return qs
```

If I apply `prefetch_related('inotes__article')` to `qs`, I get roughly what I want - three queries:

1. SELECT ••• FROM "auth_user"
2. SELECT ••• FROM "testapp_inote" WHERE "testapp_inote"."Author_id" IN ('1', '2', '3', ...)
3. SELECT ••• FROM "testapp_article" INNER JOIN "testapp_inote" ON ("testapp_article"."inote_ptr_id" = "testapp_inote"."id") WHERE "testapp_article"."inote_ptr_id" IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')

But I cann't know what inote is article and in this regard I have used `if hasattr(i,'article')` to distinguish its. And I wanted to solve this problem through Prefetch, but if I do this:

```
    prefetch = Prefetch("inotes", Inote.objects.filter(article__isnull=False))

    qs = super(UserList, self).get_queryset().prefetch_related(prefetch)
```

then I have many queries for each inote in my db.

Then I tried `Prefetch("inotes__article", Inote.objects.filter(article__isnull=False)`, but has FieldError on `inotes__article`.

How to use correctly Prefetch to solve my problem. Could you share examples or links about complex queries in such cases?

Thanks

Comment: In your case, for (easy) queryset, just use `django_polymorphic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to use `select_related` on `article` to join articles to your prefetched `inotes`. What I mean:

```py
prefetch = Prefetch("inotes", Inote.objects.select_related('article').filter(article__isnull=False))
...
```

This way Django won't need to fetch `article` when you access it during `if hasattr(i,'article'):`